# Call Javascript function multiple times in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a search results list generated by a foreach loop. I am trying to add a button to each result, to open each search result in an iframe window, but only the first result works, not the others. I would like to be able to open one or more results in iframes in the same page. and be able to close them by clicking another button. Any ideas? Thanks

```
     foreach($this->result['web']->results->result as $item) {
 echo "<ul>";
 echo "<li><a href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title."</a></li>";
 echo "<li>".$item->abstract."</li>";
 echo "<script>$(function(){
 $('#button').click(function(){
 if(!$('#iframe').length) {
 $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id=\"iframe\" src=\"".$item->url."\"    width=100% height=\"600\"></iframe>');
}
});   
});</script>";       
echo"<li><a id=\"button\">Open</a></li>";
echo"<div id='iframeHolder'></div>";
echo "</ul>";
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: you only need one copy of the script, get the `$item->url` fmom the clicked on link

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your approach, I'll try to enumerate them.

1. You are using **repeated** IDs in your DOM (`button`). IDs should be **unique**.
   Use **classes** for repeatability. Check the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for more info.
2. Your jQuery selector is using the IDs to bind the click function to the buttons.
   Every time you add a button, you bind **all buttons** to the function.
3. You should have a **generic** click function that receives an **event**.
   Check [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for ways to fetch the clicked element from the event.

---

This will only help you a little. The last mile includes adding the item URL to your `button` or `li`.

I recommend using a `data-x` attribute, that you can fetch using jQuery's `#data()` function (e.g. `target.data('x')`). In order to avoid setting the attribute value as the item URL, set it to an array index, for example.

Lastly, add your `script` tag to the end of the DOM, or in the head/separate file wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` call. It's best if it only runs **after** everything finished loading.

Comment: prefect answer +1 .. but I hope he can got this

Comment: Unfortunately PHP is a way into web development that sometimes neglects HTML and Javascript fundamentals (been there). As new as many concepts in this answer may look to beginners, some googleing and reading gets one up and running in no time.

Comment: Totally agree (concepts , googling and reading) this is how to be a professional in any field  nice to see you here :)